# Trying to make a search button that can redirect to another URL and also copy the redirected URL on clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

Here is my HTML code:

```
  <input id="text" type="text" name="text">
    <input type="button" name="page1" onclick="javascript:window.open('http://example.com/' + this.name + '/' + document.getElementById('text').value)">
```

If you put any text in the field it and click on the button it will redirect to `http://example.com/page1/anytext`
I'm trying to make this button to be able to redirect to the URL and also copy it to clipboard. So if any visitor put `anytext` on the field it will copy the url `http://example.com/page1/anytext` and also redirect to the URL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

As follows:

```
function myCopyFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("page1");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("Copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
```

Comment: Do I have to put this code like this? 
`<input type="button" name="page1" onclick="function myCopyFunction() { var copyText = document.getElementById("page1"); copyText.select(); document.execCommand("Copy"); alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value); }>`

Comment: Put functions declarations outside your HTML